# Get value from input (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following inputs and need their values:

```
<input type="hidden" ng-model="movie" value="harry_potter"/>
<input type="text" ng-model="year" value="2000"/>
```

What can I do to get the value of each input?

Comment: provide your controller code

Answer (score 31):

If you want to get values in Javascript on frontend, you can use the native way to do it by using :

```
document.getElementsByName("movie")[0].value;
```

Where `"movie"` is the name of your `input` `<input type="text" name="movie">`

If you want to get it on angular.js controller, you can use;

```
$scope.movie
```

Comment: There is no `document.getElementByName()` function. You're missing an '**s**' in the function name, and that function returns an array, so it would be `document.getElementsByName("movie")[0].value` (*assuming you only have 1 element with that name*).

Comment: Can we get a valid answer here that is actually best practice? $scope.movie / similiar $scope accessing does not work

Comment: I get property value does not exist on NodelistOf<HTMLElement>.

Answer (score 4):

If your markup is bound to a controller, directive or anything else with a [$scope](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope):

`console.log($scope.movie);`

Comment: I tried to do this way but I got "undefined"

Comment: Yeah me too.  What is the deal with this?

Comment: @light24bulbs exactly i m also facing undefined ? what is the issue

Comment: Someone? anyone? can we please get some answers here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31988632/ng-model-is-undefined-in-controller you have to use object.property notation (in your case for instance $scope.movie.title)

Comment: You can use the ng-init directive to set the initial value of $scope.movie. If you put the initial value in the `value` attribute, angular won't pick it up. e.g. `<input ng-model="movie" ng-init="movie='harry_potter'" />`