# Angular JS password match not working

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to implement an password match validation in Angular JS on my webpage and for some reason it doesn't work. I have follow religiously a step by step and implemented the method from the controller as well as i downloaded the angular file, which is in a folder called includes. Even tough it doesn't seem to work. Can someone give me a help?

My field on the register page

```
<html lang="en-US" ng-app="myApp">

<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/fintechjobs.js"></script>

      <style>

      .msg-block {
          margin-top:5px;
      }
      .msg-error {
          color:#F00;
          font-size:14px;
      }

      </style>

</head>

    <body class="size-1140" ng-controller="stageController">

    <form name="myForm" class="customform" method="POST" action="registercandidate.php" >

    <input type="password" name="pw1" id="pw1" ng-model="pw1" ng-required="" placeholder="Password"><br>
                  <input type="password" name="pw2" id="pw2" ng-model="pw2" ng-required="" pw-check="pw1" placeholder="Confirm Password"><br>

                    <div class="msg-block" ng-show="myForm.$error">
                      <span class="msg-error" ng-show="myForm.pw2.$error.pwmatch">Passwords don't match.</span>
                  </div>


    <input type="submit" class="button button-dark-stroke text-size-12" value="Submit" style="width:100px;">


    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my JS file with the Angular app

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.directives']);
/* Controllers */
function stageController($scope) {
    $scope.pw1 = 'pw1';
}
/* Directives */
angular.module('myApp.directives', [])
    .directive('pwCheck', [function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            var firstPassword = '#' + attrs.pwCheck;
            elem.add(firstPassword).on('keyup', function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    // console.info(elem.val() === $(firstPassword).val());
                    ctrl.$setValidity('pwmatch', elem.val() === $(firstPassword).val());
                });
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Any particular reason that wouldn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please set Your ng-model in this format

```
ng-model="object.pw1"
```

instead of

```
ng-model="pw1"
```

and then try also change the value wherever you have used ng-model

See this link for more details

[object in ng-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31988632/ng-model-is-undefined-in-controller)