# Get value input with angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have to get the value of an input text with AngularJS but without using Controller.
How i can get this value?
I saw this posts but uses .controller
[link post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21040454/get-value-from-input-angularjs)

Comment: You can use angular.element: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: Just curious: why don't you use a controller?

Comment: we can not use a controller. project requirements....

Comment: why use angularJS then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code, with angular.element:

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#your_input_tag_id')).val();
```

or, with simple jQuery:

```
$('#your_input_tag_id').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than querying the DOM for elements (which isn't very angular see How do I "think in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?) you should perform your DOM manipulation within your directive. The element is available to you in your link function.

So in your myDirective

`return {
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
        element.html('Hello world');
    }
}`

If you must perform the query outside of the directive then it would be possible to use querySelectorAll in modern browers

```
angular.element(document.querySelectorAll("[my-directive]"));
$('#your_input_tag_id').val();
```

however you would need to use jquery to support IE8 and backwards

```
angular.element($("[my-directive]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

make your input a model and the value will always be available as the model

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myModelName">
```

and then your value will be available within the scope of your module as myModelName

```
console.log('value = ' + $scope.myModelName);
```

, if you are trying to get the value from somewhere other than the scope of the module or app then you are probably doing it wrong and not the angular way, it really is best to use a controller or link function even if it's the main app controller or link function, and you would be well placed to push back on any requirement not to use a controller (which sounds like a bad or misunderstood requirement).