# Firebase password and email authentification fails with error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I'm developing an app using the newest versions/SDK of

1. Visual Studio
2. Cordova
3. Ionic
4. AngularJS
5. Firebase
6. Genymotion

and I try to auth a user in my app via Firebase (email and password).
I already searched the web for a solution but I simply don't get it working correctly.

Well, as soon as I click the register button (top right corner) I'll get this error message

[image: Error message]

## This is the register.html (contains a form)

```
<ion-modal-view>
<div class="bar bar-header firstStart">
    <div class="button button-clear button-positive" ng-click="closeModal()">
       Schließen
    </div>
    <h1 class="title modalTitle">Registrieren </h1>
    <div class="button button-clear button-positive"
         ng-click="signupEmail()"> Speichern </div>
</div>

<ion-content class="has-header" padding="true">
    <div class="list list-inset">
        <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-email placeholder-icon"></i>
            <span class="input-label">E-Mail</span>
            <input type="email" ng-model="data.email" placeholder="E-Mail" id="email">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-locked placeholder-icon"></i>
            <span class="input-label">Passwort</span>
            <input type="password" ng-model="data.password"
                   placeholder="Passwort" id="password">
        </label>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

## app.js

```
    .controller('modalController', ['$scope', '$ionicModal','$firebase', 
     function ($scope, $ionicModal,$firebase)
     {
        $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/register.html', {
        scope: $scope,
        animation: 'slide-in-up',
        backdropClickToClose: false,
        hardwareBackButtonClose: false,
        focusFirstInput: true
    }).then(function (modal) {
        $scope.modal = modal;
    });

    $scope.signupEmail = function () {
        $scope.data = {};
        var email = $scope.data.email;
        alert(email);
        var password = $scope.data.password;
        alert(password);
        /*if (email.length < 4) {
            alert('Please enter an email address.');
            return;
        }
        if (password.length < 4) {
            alert('Please enter a password.');
            return;
        }*/

        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(
        function (error)
        {
            // Handle Errors here.
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            if (errorCode == 'auth/weak-password') {
                alert('The password is too weak.');
            } else {
                alert(errorMessage);
            }
            if (errorCode == 'auth/argument-error') {
                alert('Error with arg');
            } else {
                alert(errorMessage);
            }
            console.log(error);
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        });
        // [END createwithemail]
    };

    $scope.login = function () {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
            if (user) {
                // User is signed in.
                alert("User already signed in");
            } else {
                // No user is signed in.
                firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(
              function (error)
              {
                 // Handle Errors here.
                 var errorCode = error.code;
                 var errorMessage = error.message;
                 alert("error during login:" + errorMessage + "Code: " + errorCode);
               })
            }
        });
    };

    $scope.openModal = function () {
        $scope.modal.show();
    };

    $scope.closeModal = function () {
        $scope.modal.hide();
    };
    // Cleanup the modal when we're done with it!
    $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        $scope.modal.remove();
    });
    // Execute action on hide modal
    $scope.$on('modal.hidden', function () {
        // Execute action
    });
    // Execute action on remove modal
    $scope.$on('modal.removed', function () {
        // Execute action
    });
}]);
```

Please note that app.js contains two controller because one modal opens another modal if the user taps on the button at the top right corner

## This function causes the error

This function is placed in app.js, just wanted to highlight it for you.

```
$scope.signupEmail = function () {
    $scope.data = {};
    var email = $scope.data.email;
    alert(email);
    var password = $scope.data.password;
    alert(password);

    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(
        function (error) 
        {
           // Handle Errors here.
           var errorCode = error.code;
           var errorMessage = error.message;
           // [START_EXCLUDE]
           if (errorCode == 'auth/weak-password') {
             alert('The password is too weak.');
           } else {
            alert(errorMessage);
           }
           if (errorCode == 'auth/argument-error') {
            alert('Error with arg');
           } else {
            alert(errorMessage);
           }
           console.log(error);
           // [END_EXCLUDE]
       });
       // [END createwithemail]
     };
```

**Note:** As you may see I'm printing out the password and email the user typed in to see its value but the only result I get is
[image: Alert message]

What am I doing wrong?
Your answers are very appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.data = {};

var email = $scope.data.email;
alert(email);

var password = $scope.data.password;
alert(password);
```

Email is always undefined.

Comment: I thought that since I bind the value of my input field in 'register.html' with '<input type="email" ng-model="data.email" placeholder="E-Mail" id="email">' to my variable 'var email = $scope.data.email' in my controller , I'll get the value of what the user is typing in...How can I accomplish that? If the user is filling in the form, I want to gather the information and use it. Thought I'd do that with data binding (ng-data)

Comment: Like he suggested  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21040454/get-value-from-input-angularjs)