# Get angular ng-model value in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Just i want to get the ng-model hidden field value using javascript.

```
<input type="hidden" name="Latitude" id="sLatitude" ng-model='sLatitude'>
```

Comment: In controller, you can get is by `$scope.sLatitude`.

Comment: [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446359/angularjs-does-not-send-hidden-field-value)

Comment: Hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21040454/2401386) helps you.

Comment: do u want get the value to controller or outside of the controller

Answer (score 2):

it took me some time to find out, but I think the answer is

```
angular.element(YOUR_ANGULAR_ELEMENT_HERE).attr('ng-model');
```

As an answer you 'll get the value of the ng-model, "sLatitude".

I am leaving it here just in case someone else needs it.

Answer (score 0):

you can get sLatitude value by :

```
console.log($scope.sLatitude);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want that value within scope , just access as `$scope.sLatitude`

If you want that value outside the scope, `document.getElementById("sLatitude").value`

Answer (score 0):

You can access by calling:

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('sLatitude')).scope().sLatitude
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of Latitude by write this in java script in your controller like this.
var latotudeValue = $scope.sLatitude;

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of Latitude by $scope.

var latitudeValue = $scope.sLatitude;

OR

if you have **value** attribute in input control then

var latitudeValue = document.getElementsById("sLatitude").value;